# Solving the integral of the equation of a mixed model in R

Tags: r, statistics, regression, mixed-models

I am working with mixed effects models and due to the specifics of my methodology
I need to solve the integral of the model below and later make a graph
of the estimates obtained.

In other words, I need to solve the integral below:
[image]

where, `di^2` is `Var3` in my model and `dh` is the function that corresponds to the mixed effects model.

In the literature on the problem in which I am inserted, there are few works that have used
of mixed effects models for this purpose, the vast majority work only with regression models
simple linear. However, for my problem it is necessary to use mixed models.

The model is defined by:

[image]

where the random effect `bi` was introduced in the intercept considering the variable `Var2`.

Considering only the fixed part of the model, that is, a fixed effects model, the procedure I performed to solve the integral was as follows:

Data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hFb1OPO0jxQw7_u62swnkRXbOH81ygDD/view?usp=sharing

I apologize for hosting the data in a link, however, I couldn't find an internal R database that has variables that might match my problem.

```
fitmixedmodel <-  lme(log(Var1)~I(exp(Var3/Var4))+ 
                            (I((Var5/Var4)^3)),
                          random = ~1|Var2, 
                          dados, method="REML")
summary(fitmixedmodel)
volume <- dados[dados$Var5 == 0.1,]
fmixedmodel <- function(Var3, Var5, Var4){
  (pi/40000)*(Var3^2)*(coefficients(summary(fitmixedmodel))[1] + 
                           coefficients(summary(fitmixedmodel))[2]*I(exp(Var3/Var4)) + 
                           coefficients(summary(fitmixedmodel))[3]*(I((Var5/Var4)^3)))
}
vmixedmodel <- function(Var3, Var5, Var4){ 
  integrate(Vectorize(fmixedmodel), lower = 0.1, upper = Var4, Var3 = Var3, Var4 = Var4)$value
  
}
mixed.vol <- mapply(FUN = vmixedmodel,  
                       Var5 = as.list(volume$Var5),
                       Var3 = as.list(volume$Var3),
                       Var4 = as.list(volume$Var4))
```

And so I get the following graph.

[image]

However, notice that in the calculation of this integral at no point do I declare the random effect, that is, I am integrating the function only from the fixed part and not taking into account the random part either. How could I solve this problem, that is, actually integrate the adjusted mixed model equation?

Comment: Interesting question, however, it's off topic here since it's not a specific programming question. I think stats.stackexchange.com is more appropriate.

Comment: Hi Robert, ok!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded your dataset as Data.csv.  I had to do some formatting to get it to work on my local machine:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(nlme)
library(data.table)


##################
# Format data   ##
##################


dat <- read.table("Data.csv", 
                  sep=";", 
                  dec=",", 
                  colClasses=c("character",
                                rep("numeric",4)), 
                  skip=1)
setDT(dat)
format(dat,decimal.mark=".")

dat[, Var2 := V1]
dat[, Var3 := as.numeric(V2)]
dat[, Var4 := as.numeric(V3)]
dat[, Var1 := as.numeric(V4)]
dat[, Var5 := as.numeric(V5)]
dat

## this is name used in OP code
dados <- copy(dat[,c("Var2","Var3","Var4","Var1","Var5")])
```

I rewrote the code a little bit so I could reproduce your graphic --
Here's your code with some minor formatting changes:

```
################### BEGIN OP CODE ####################

fitmixedmodel <-  lme( log(Var1) ~  I(exp(Var3/Var4))+ I((Var5/Var4)^3),
                      random = ~1|Var2, 
                      data = dados, 
                      method="REML")

summary(fitmixedmodel)

volume <- dados[dados$Var5 == 0.1,]

fmixedmodel <- function(Var3, Var5, Var4){
  (pi/40000)*
  (Var3^2)*
  (coefficients(summary(fitmixedmodel))[1] + 
   coefficients(summary(fitmixedmodel))[2]*I(exp(Var3/Var4)) + 
   coefficients(summary(fitmixedmodel))[3]*(I((Var5/Var4)^3)))
}

vmixedmodel <- function(Var3, Var5, Var4){ 
  integrate(Vectorize(fmixedmodel), 
            lower = 0.1, 
            upper = Var4, 
            Var3 = Var3,  
            Var4 = Var4)$value  
}

mixed.vol <- mapply(FUN = vmixedmodel,  
                    Var5 = as.list(volume$Var5),
                    Var3 = as.list(volume$Var3),
                    Var4 = as.list(volume$Var4))

################# END OP CODE ##################
```

```
## now verify the graph.  looks good.
ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(y=mixed.vol, x=volume$Var3, color=volume$Var3))
```

So at this point I was able to reproduce your graphic.

I initially thought there were two options for incorporating random intercepts.  One is to "integrate them out" which would involve the variance of the random intercepts and a double integral.  But it turns out for linear regression this type of marginalization doesn't change the outcome.  To prove this to ourselves, look at the following code that goes through the trouble of fitting a double integral to integrate out the random intercept `b` that follows a Normal(0, 0.1691067^2) distribution.  Because the integral with respect to `b` can just isolate `b` by itself and the E[b] = 0, this approach is not materially different than the OP approach.

```
# Option 1: integrate over the random intercept distribution
# this will require the random intercept variance as well as 
# double integration.

## to be able to accommodate a random intercept, we need to integrate
## over the random intercepts, which are distributed as N(0, sig2)
## where sig2 is 0.1691067^2 as seen from the fitmixedmodel output:

# 
# Random effects:
#   Formula: ~1 | Var2
#          (Intercept)  Residual
# StdDev:   0.1691067 0.2559742
```

```
## add "b" random intercept, multiply whole thing by normal density dnorm
integrand <- function(x,  Var3, Var4){
  
  Var5 <- x[1]
  b <- x[2]
  
  (pi/40000)*(Var3^2)*
  (coefficients(summary(fitmixedmodel))[1] + b  + 
   coefficients(summary(fitmixedmodel))[2]*I(exp(Var3/Var4)) + 
   coefficients(summary(fitmixedmodel))[3]*(I((Var5/Var4)^3))) *
    dnorm(b, sd = 0.1691067)
}

vmixedmodel.option1 <- function(Var5, Var3, Var4){ 
  pcubature(integrand, 
            lower = c(0.1,-Inf), 
             upper = c(Var4,Inf), 
             Var3 = Var3, 
             Var4 = Var4)$integral  
}

## this is slow. And unnecessary.  Because the E[b] = 0
mixed.vol.option1 <- mapply(FUN = vmixedmodel.option1,  
                            Var5 = as.list(volume$Var5),
                            Var3 = as.list(volume$Var3),
                            Var4 = as.list(volume$Var4))

max(abs(mixed.vol - mixed.vol.option1))

ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(y=mixed.vol.option1, x=volume$Var3, color=volume$Var3))
```

The second approach is plugging in the estimated random intercept value, much like how the OP approach plugs in values for `Var4` and `Var3`. To pursue this avenue, we first create `volume_ri` which is the same as the `volume` dataset but has the estimate values of b:

```
## Option 2: plug in the random intercept value.

rand_int <- data.table(Var2 = rownames(fitmixedmodel$coeff$random$Var2), 
                          b = fitmixedmodel$coeff$random$Var2 )
setnames(rand_int, names(rand_int), c("Var2","b"))
rand_int

## merge into `volume` (or `dados` and then re-subset)
volume_ri <- merge(volume,
                   rand_int)
```

And then basically we adust the OP code to accommodate this `b` as an argument or value where appropriate:

```
## throw in a b argument
fmixedmodel_ri <- function(Var3, Var5, Var4, b){
  (pi/40000)*
    (Var3^2)*
    (coefficients(summary(fitmixedmodel))[1] + b + 
       coefficients(summary(fitmixedmodel))[2]*I(exp(Var3/Var4)) + 
       coefficients(summary(fitmixedmodel))[3]*(I((Var5/Var4)^3)))
}

## throw in a b argument
vmixedmodel_ri <- function(Var3, Var5, Var4, b){ 
  integrate(Vectorize(fmixedmodel_ri), 
            lower = 0.1, 
            upper = Var4, 
            Var3 = Var3,  
            Var4 = Var4,
               b = b)$value  
}

## plug in the b values
mixed.vol_ri <- mapply(FUN = vmixedmodel_ri,  
                      Var5 = as.list(volume_ri$Var5),
                      Var3 = as.list(volume_ri$Var3),
                      Var4 = as.list(volume_ri$Var4),
                         b = as.list(volume_ri$b))

## now verify the graph. only 8 levels of Var2, so use color
ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(y=mixed.vol_ri, x=volume_ri$Var3, color=volume_ri$Var2))
```

---

### Below are old questions that are answered in comments

Old questions:

My concern/confusion is the line where I comment DID YOU MEAN `Var5 = Var5` -- would you mind double checking that. and leaving me a comment with the answer?

Also, a separate question regarding accounting for the random intercept:

do you want to integrate over all random intercept values

**or**

do you want to plug in the random intercept estimate for each unique Var2 from the mixed model fit?

Comment: Hi @swihart, thanks for your reply. Regarding your question whether Var3=Var3 should be ````Var5=Var5````, no. I will explain to you why. The variable ````Var3```` refers to a variable that controls the thickness of the object I'm evaluating, so it's ````Var3=Var3````.
The argument ````upper=Var4```` is due to the fact that Var4 refers to the total length of the object of study. Therefore, I am integrating the volume of each of these individuals taking into account their total length and thickness. So, the arguments I present in my code are correct.

Comment: Regarding my question, is how to introduce random effects in this integration. In fact, I would be interested in the two situations described by you, namely all random intercept values ​​and also plug in the random intercept estimate for each unique Var2 from the mixed model fit. So as soon as you introduce such solutions I accept the answer. Thanks for your availability.